# Angular optional language parameter on parent route path

Tags: angular

I have an angular app that has several countries urls and each country could have several languages.
My app main routing has two different options

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './country/country.module#CountryModule'
  },
  {
    path: ':countryCode/:languageCode',
    loadChildren: './views/views.module#ViewsModule'
  },
  {
    path: ':countryCode',
    loadChildren: './views/views.module#ViewsModule'
  }
]
```

So the root path goes to a country/language selector view and the other two go to the views module. If the country language selected is the primary language the path only contains countrycode but if the selected language is not primary the languageCode if added to url

The views module also has a routing module, that redirects to each view

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path : '',  component: ViewsComponent,
    children : [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
      { path: ':catUrl1/:catUrl2', component: CategoryComponent},
      { path: ':catUrl1', component: CategoryComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

So urls like my.app.com/us and my.app.com/us/es show home component. The problem comes with category component
While navigating to second level category with primary and secondary languages and first level category with secondary languages works fine and navigates to category component showing the right route params

```
my.app.com/us/tv/oled-c1234 -> second level primary lang
my.app.com/us/es/tv/oled-c1234 -> second level secondary lang
my.app.com/us/es/media-c7890 -> first level secondary lang
```

The problem comes with first level category and primary lang

my.app.com/us/media-c7890

The app is showing home component instead of category component as the last part of url (media-c7890) is taken as languageCode variable instead of catUrl1.

Is there any way to get it to work the way I want?

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lyupt9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fviews%2Fviews.component.ts)

After some more research it turns out that categories with primary language are not working at all, so when i try to reach first level category it matches home component while trying to get second level category matches first level category. The catUrl1 path variable is taken as languageCode when no secondary language is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution by using a custom matcher, so my main routes are :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './country/country.module#CountryModule'
  },
  {
    path: CustomURLMatcher.languageMatcher
    loadChildren: './views/views.module#ViewsModule'
  }
]
```

And my custom matcher looks like :

```
export class URLMatcher {
  private isCountryOrLanguage(code: string) {
    return /[a-z]{2})$/.test(code);
  }

  languageMatcher = (url: UrlSegment[], segmentGroup: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route) => {
    if (!url.length) {
      return null;
    }
    if (url[1] && this.isCountryOrLanguage(url[1].path)) {
      const consumed = [url[0], url[1]];
      const posParams = { countryCode: url[0], languageCode: url[1] };
      return { consumed, posParams };
    } else if (!url[1] || (url[1] && !this.isCountryOrLanguage(url[1].path))) {
      const consumed = [url[0]];
      const posParams = { countryCode: url[0] };
      return { consumed, posParams };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

export const CustomURLMatcher = new URLMatcher();
```